# get file information from DirEntry in a for loop

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am new to Rust. I am trying to build a JSON object where the keys are file names and the value is the file contents.

So far, I have:

```
use std::fs;
use std::io;
use std::env;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn main() {
    make_json();
}

fn make_json() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut modules = HashMap::new();
    let mut dir = env::current_dir().unwrap();
    let mut read_dir = fs::read_dir(dir);

    for entry in try!(read_dir) {
        let entry = try!(entry);
        let file_name = entry.path().file_name().unwrap().to_string_lossy();
        modules.insert(file_name, "");
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

When I go to compile it, I get

```
src/main.rs:19:25: 19:37 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
src/main.rs:19         let file_name = entry.path().file_name().unwrap().to_string_lossy();
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:17:5: 21:6 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:13:38: 23:2 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 13:37...
src/main.rs:13     let mut modules = HashMap::new();
src/main.rs:14     let mut dir = env::current_dir().unwrap();
src/main.rs:15     let mut read_dir = fs::read_dir(dir);
src/main.rs:16 
src/main.rs:17     for entry in try!(read_dir) {
src/main.rs:18         let entry = try!(entry);
               ...
src/main.rs:19:9: 19:77 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the statement at 19:8
src/main.rs:19         let file_name = entry.path().file_name().unwrap().to_string_lossy();
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:19:9: 19:77 help: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
src/main.rs:19         let file_name = entry.path().file_name().unwrap().to_string_lossy();
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

**I understand what this error is telling me**; entry is defined within the scope of the `for` loop, and therefore if I store it to the `HashMap` it will no longer be valid memory because the place in memory will have been freed already. I get that.

What I don't get, is how I access the the `DirEntry`s within `read_dir` without using some sort of closure, since I will need their information outside of whatever closure I retrieve them in.

Everything that I have come across hasn't been able to help me.

Comment: The code you posted is not the code you compiled. Please ensure that it is, and also adjust it to something that runs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DirEntry.path()` returns a `PathBuf`, which is `'static` (i.e. it contains no non-static references and is a completely standalong object). *It* is where the problem lies.

`PathBuf.file_name()` returns `Option<&OsStr>`, a reference into that object, and [`OsStr.to_string_lossy()` returns `Cow<str>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html#method.to_string_lossy). Note with that last that it is *not* `'static`; with the elided lifetimes reinstated, it’s `fn to_string_lossy<'a>(&'a self) -> Cow<'a, str>`. This is for efficiency, because if the path is legal UTF-8 then there’s no need to go creating an entirely new owned string (`String`), it can keep it as a string slice (`&str`). (Because that’s what `Cow<'a, str>` is: its variants, with generics filled in, are `Owned(String)` and `Borrowed(&'a str)`.)

What you need in this location is to turn the `Cow<str>` into a `String`. This is accomplished with the [`into_owned` method of `Cow<T>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html#method.into_owned).

That line of code thus becomes this:

```
let file_name = entry.path().file_name().unwrap().to_string_lossy().into_owned();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem while dealing with Rust file system forced me to create this rust library [brown](https://crates.io/crates/brown)

While dealing with Rust fs and specially while working with loops, the main issue is that every thing return another thing and then we need to convert that thing.
**We need something to flatten the items for us**

> My suggestion :: Do not do any calculations etc in a loop, it should just have function calls to a well tested library and just checking its results.